# Specifying http-proxy when using the boxsdk for Python?

Tags: python, proxy

When running behind a firewall, I get the error "getaddrinfo failed" on the last line of this sample Python program.  Is there a way to specify a proxy server for the client() connection being made through the boxsdk?

```
# coding: utf-8

from boxsdk import Client, OAuth2
from boxsdk.network.default_network import DefaultNetwork

# code here to set IDs and Tokens, used in oauth2, below

oauth2 = OAuth2(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN)

client = Client(oauth2)

my = client.user(user_id='me').get()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is!

The Python Boxsdk uses the requests module; requests supports obtaining a proxy value from the environment variables http_proxy and https_proxy.  The value of https_proxy should be https://proxy:port.

Set the environment variables via the appropriate OS commands and it should work fine.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

When you create the Client object, you can pass your proxy server details and BoxSDK will handle your proxy configuration.
Also as BoxSDK uses the requests library, make sure you pass the proxy in the format:

```
http://username:password@host:port
```